# ThreadingHTTPServer eventually stops accepting sockets on macOS

Tags: python, macos, sockets

I'm running into a weird issue on macOS + Python (macOS 12.6.2, Python 3.10.7 from python.org) when using a ThreadingHTTPServer to serve requests, although I suspect the issue might not be limited to ThreadingHTTPServer. After around an hour or two of serving requests, the server eventually stops accepting new connections entirely. Using `lsof -T fqs`, I can see the server socket has a full listening queue:

`Python  12345  user    3u     IPv4 0xf0c5647762f3efe1       0t0       TCP *:8881 (LISTEN QR=0 QS=0 SO=ACCEPTCONN,PQLEN=5,QLEN=5,QLIM=5,RCVBUF=1048576,REUSEADDR,SNDBUF=1048576 TF=MSS=512,UNKNOWN=0xa0)`

Note that `QLEN` is the number of established inbound connections that have not been accepted yet. `QLEN` is initially 0, and seems to gradually increase over time (right now, for the process that's been running for ~30 minutes, it's 3).

When I check the process with `spindump`, I can see that the main thread is spending most of its time (>99.5%) in `select_poll_poll -> poll`, but I also see a couple of other calls, indicating that the process is occasionally breaking out of the `poll` call. This is expected: `socketserver.BaseServer.serve_forever` calls `selector.select` (which calls `poll`) with a short timeout in a loop. `serve_forever` accepts exactly one socket each time `selector.select` returns successfully.

From this, it looks like the program is somehow failing to accept listening sockets. I'm not doing anything fancy in my code, so I wonder if this could possibly be a bug with poll() on macOS (which [would not be the first time](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/10/11/poll-on-mac-10-12-is-broken/)) or in the way in which Python is using poll() for server sockets on macOS?

The program itself is a proxy server using a vanilla ThreadingHTTPServer with a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclassed to handle CONNECT, GET, POST etc. I'm running connections from two clients through the proxy. The code looks like this:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer

class ProxyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_CONNECT(self): ...
    def do_other(self): ...
    do_GET = do_other
    do_POST = do_other
    do_PUT = do_other
    do_DELETE = do_other
    do_PATCH = do_other
    do_OPTIONS = do_other

server = ThreadingHTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8881), ProxyHandler)
print("Serving on %s:%d" % server.server_address)
try:
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught Ctrl+C, exiting...")

server.server_close()
```

I've omitted the implementations of `do_CONNECT` and `do_other` because I don't believe they're relevant: these functions run in their own thread (per ThreadingHTTPServer) and should not affect the main thread.

Comment: Hmm, this is getting weird. I changed `serve_forever` to just call accept() in a loop. The queue is still leaking, so the culprit is not poll() or select(). I can’t figure out what connections are leaking via netstat. My temporary workaround will be to make the listen backlog 120, which should allow it to keep running for a day or so. In the long run, though, I’d love to figure out what’s going on here…